# angular update scope's properties on view issue

Tags: angularjs

I have following object in my scope with property `status` which is **OPENED** by default

```
$scope.task = {
     status: 'OPENED'
}
```

All i want to do is change this status on click. [Here is a simple scenario](http://plnkr.co/edit/jLwXlOvWcMQmu2IMu0FL?p=preview) how it should work. But in my real project request sends to server and changes status in database so it takes some time.

Basically it looks like this:

```
$scope.changeStatus = function (task, status) {
        task.status = status;
        task.$update();
    };
```

So when this method is invoked at first I change status in my `$scope.task` and it changes immediately on my view(thanks to bi-directional data binding) but two buttons appear at the same time as well. Then after a few milliseconds the second button gone. I am wondering what is the best way to fix it? Should i create a copy of scope object or is there other ways?

Comment: Could you show the html of the buttons? Also you might now want to change buttons until the call is actually done so you don't give false user feedback.

Comment: look at the plunker i've attached

Comment: Why not just use one button/anchor and toggle the text change?

Comment: cause not only text is changing, if you will take a look a the plunker, you will see that buttons call method with different arguments (OPENED and CLOSED)

Comment: so change the text and supply it with different arguments? I still don't see why you need two buttons to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using $resource for your $update() method. You can use the promise that the functions return.

> It's worth noting that the success callback for get, query and other methods gets passed in the response that came from the server as well as $http header getter function

From [$resource @ angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(u, getResponseHeaders){
  u.abc = true;
  u.$save(function(u, putResponseHeaders) {
    //u => saved user object
    //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
  });
});
```

So in your case:

```
$scope.changeStatus = function (task, status) {
        task.status = status;
        task.$update(function() { $scope.task.status = status });
    };
```

Comment: Yes I am using $resource. I did not mention it and it may get confused, cause in my real project i actually use for each by $scope.tasks and render this in table. In front of each task i have a button with a method to change status. So parameter task in function changeStatus(task, status){...}  is actually an object of array $scope.tasks. So in this case  $scope.task.status = status will not suit me.

Comment: Well that wasn't stated as your original question. You can use $index inside your ng-repeat for each button in order to know which index of your array you need updated.